# Problem about link clicking with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need your help... this is getting me crazy :

```
mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()
reg_url="https://etherscan.io/token/0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2da=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

mydriver.get(reg_url)
iframe = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='tokentxnsiframe']") 
mydriver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

count_added = 0

while cond : 

    elems = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="maindiv"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[8]/a')

    #DOING THING WITH THE elems
mydriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)") 


    time.sleep(5)

    element = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maindiv"]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[4]/a')

    actions = webdriver.ActionChains(mydriver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    actions.click().perform()

    time.sleep(5)
```

Page HTML is:

```
<div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
   <p class="mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <i id="spinwheel" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner fa-1x fa-pulse mr-1" style="display: none;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc mr-1" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Oldest First"></i>A total of 9,725 transactions found
   </p>
   <nav aria-label="page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm mb-0">
         <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">First</span></li>
         <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left small"></i></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></li>
         <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link text-nowrap">Page <strong class="font-weight-medium">1</strong> of <strong class="font-weight-medium">389</strong></span></li>
         <li class="page-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Go to Next"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:move('generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d&amp;mode=&amp;sid=4b6ef2c27b590c4f6cd4bef249b5ced6&amp;a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&amp;m=normal&amp;p=2')" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="True"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right small"></i></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li>
         <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:move('generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d&amp;mode=&amp;sid=4b6ef2c27b590c4f6cd4bef249b5ced6&amp;a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&amp;m=normal&amp;p=389')"><span aria-hidden="True">Last</span> <span class="sr-only">Last</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Basically I want the script to click on the next page link on the frame to go to the next page. Instead of going there, it's clicking to some random link.
I've tried to get more specific on finding the link with `mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@area-label="Next"]')` but I get the same result.

Comment: Add html and mark which code line has a problem

Comment: The is no code problem, it's just clicking on the wrong link.
"https://etherscan.io/token/0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d?a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" should click on the next page here .
Instead click and redirect here :
"https://etherscan.io/token/0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d?a=1000187527#inventory"

Comment: There are code problems, but it is another issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to use xpath like that:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='page-link' and @aria-label='Next'])[1]")
```

Comment: Still same problem, it sending me to "https://etherscan.io/token/0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d?a=1000198760#inventory"

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo and that one? "(//li[@data-original-title='Go to Next'])[1]"

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo works for me greatly, weird(

Answer (score 0):

Try css selector below:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("nav li[data-original-title="Go to Next"]>.page-link")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(mydriver, 10)
mydriver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0x85f0e02cb992aa1f9f47112f815f519ef1a59e2d?a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#btnCookie"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("tokentxnsiframe"))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@aria-label='Next']"))).click()
```

You should remove the element on top first and then switch to the iframe and click the next button.Also start using webdriver wait to ensure the stability of your programs instead of time.sleep().

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

[image]